# Make two or more graphs have the same scale

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2013

I have several area graphs in an Excel spreadsheet. I want all of those graphs to have exactly the same scale.

Each of the graphs have a measurement in meters on each of the axes. I want each of the axes to be exactly proportional to each other, so not like this:

[image]

But (roughly) like this (the image is squished, this is just a demonstration, I need Excel to do that for me):

[image]

Is this possible *without* either using an image editor, or just manually scaling the graphs "by eye"?

If it's relevant, my Excel version is 2013. Also, don't worry about the graphs being upside down, they're meant to be like that.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know what you mean by “by eye”.

I constructed a couple of charts that are similar to yours:

[image: graphs with different scales]

Click on the X axis of the bottom chart, right click → Format Axis:

[image: "Format Axis" properties dialog box for chart with wider range]

Note the minimum and maximum.  Then bring up the Format Axis of the top chart and set its values to the same as the bottom chart:

[image: "Format Axis" properties dialog box for chart with smaller range]

Now the graphs have the same scale:

[image: graphs with same scale]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for area charts, but I never knew about this, and it looks quite cool, so +1. I'll accept it, and be very thankful, if you explain either how to make it work for area charts, or how to style a scatter graph like or very similarly to an area chart.

Comment: A couple of questions: (1) Do you guarantee that, in each chart, the X axis points form an arithmetic progression (e.g., 214.4 = 2×107.2, 321.7 = 3×107.2, etc.)? (2) How would you feel about having the X axes labeled something like 0, 100, 200, …, instead of the X coordinates of the data points?

Answer (score 0):

Is it worth answering a 9.5-year-old question?

Anyway, I've repro'd your chart axes below. I have two sets of data and charts for each data set. In the top chart for each data set, I'm using the default axis scale. In the bottom charts, I have changed the X axis to a date scale (it was auto, which for this data means text). I changed base units to days and major units to 100 days.

[image]

The scales still don't line up. Both start at zero, but end at different values, the maximum of each data set. So I have added another row to each data set, X=1000 and Y=0, and adjusted the charts accordingly. The charts now start at zero and end at 1000.

[image]